# SQL Average of Last 100 records

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-update, sql-order-by, sql-limit

In the query I provided below, I am trying to update the field estimated_price of all products with its relevant average: the average price of the newest 100 records of this product in inventory where the type of entity is "Quotes".

I wrote this script but I encountered the error "Unknown column 'vtiger_products.productid' in 'where clause'"

```
update `vtiger_products` set `vtiger_products`.`estimated_price` =
    (select avg(`subquery`.`unit_price`)
     from
         (select vtiger_inventoryproductrel.listprice as 'unit_price'
          from `vtiger_inventoryproductrel`
          left join `vtiger_crmentity` on `vtiger_inventoryproductrel`.`id` = `vtiger_crmentity`.`crmid`
          where `vtiger_crmentity`.`setype` = 'Quotes'
          and vtiger_inventoryproductrel.productid = vtiger_products.productid
          order by vtiger_crmentity.createdtime desc
          limit 100) as `subquery`
     )
```

I will be glad if someone helps me to find solution

Comment: try update join https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql-server

Comment: Do not use correlated subquery, use multiple-table syntax.

Comment: Are you going to run this UPDATE each time someone has made INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE? Or is old, somewhat inaccurate data fine?

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a joined update for this. And combine it with `ROW_NUMBER` to get the top 100 rows per `productid`.

Also, because the subqueries are now not correlated, you can put them in into CTEs to make them more readable.

```sql
with numbered as (
    select
      ipr.productid,
      ipr.listprice,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ipr.productid ORDER BY crm.createdtime DESC) as rn
    from vtiger_inventoryproductrel ipr
    join vtiger_crmentity crm on ipr.id = crm.crmid
    where crm.setype = 'Quotes'
),
averaged as (
    select
      n.productid,
      avg(n.listprice) as avg_price
    from numbered n
    group by
      n.productid
)
update
    vtiger_products p
    join averaged a on a.productid = p.productid and a.rn <= 100
set p.estimated_price = a.avg_price;
```